# Ubuntu rename loopback interface

Tags: ubuntu, loopback

I have a Linux box with Ubuntu 16.04. I've noticed some odd behavior when I needed use the loopback interface.

So I checked with ifconfig first and it showed that:

```
rename1   Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:326 (326.0 B)  TX bytes:326 (326.0 B)
```

ip link shows this:

```
1: rename1: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The "rename1" is not intentional and I wanted revert this to "lo".

After some search I found this command:

```
sudo ip link set rename1 name lo
```

Witch it does what I wanted, but after a restart it changes back to "rename1" and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback interface is defined in **/etc/network/interfaces** on debian and derivated.

Replace "rename1" by "lo" as root or sudoer

```
sed -i s@rename1@lo@ /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: Ho.. so what's the output of "rgrep rename1 /etc/"

Comment: This is how my interfaces file looks like:

`# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.10
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.0.1
 network 192.168.0.0
 broadcast 192.168.0.255
 dns-nameservers 192.168.0.9 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
 dns-search mydomain.com
`

Comment: The `rgrep rename1 /etc/` output is nothing too.